# Automatically rename a file if it already exists with SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#

Chamal Fernando Answer my question, really thanks,

You may use fileName without using filestream. 
Set OverwritePrompt property of Save File Dialog to false.
Then make the while loop to count up the index.

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //abre a opção de salvar como, para selecionar a pasta

```
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog
            {
                //InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonPictures),

                Filter = "JPeg Image|*.jpg|Bitmap Image|*.bmp|Gif Image|*.gif",
                Title = "Salvar o arquivo de imagem",
                RestoreDirectory = true,
            };

            saveFileDialog1.OverwritePrompt = false;
            saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

            // se o nome do arquivo não for vazio, abre para salvar
            if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
            {
                int fileCount = 0;
                string fullPath = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                string fileNamewithoutExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullPath);
                string dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
                string ext = Path.GetExtension(fullPath);
                string newPath = string.Empty;

                while (File.Exists(newPath = Path.Combine(dirPath, fileNamewithoutExt + (fileCount > 0 ? "[" + fileCount + "]" : "") + ext)))
                { fileCount++; }

                // Salva a imagem no formato certo
                switch (saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex)
                {
                    case 1:
                        this.pictureBoxScreenshot.Image.Save(newPath,
                           System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        this.pictureBoxScreenshot.Image.Save(newPath,
                           System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        this.pictureBoxScreenshot.Image.Save(newPath,
                           System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                        break;
                } 
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
```

Comment: Just stop using the SaveFileDialog.OpenFile() convenience method, it is not convenient to you.  Use the other Image.Save() overload, the one that takes a string.

Comment: @Chamal Fernando thank you!!